# Why resetting prototype does not remove the property from objects?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Im trying to get my head around javascript prototyping & possible inheritance, but I'm certainly missing something. Let's start with simple constructor (function Counter()), adding simple property and instantiation of object:

```
function Counter() { this.a = "first"; };
Counter.prototype.b = "second";
var counter = new Counter();
```

At this point, `counter.a` returns "first", `counter.b` returns "second" and `counter.c` is of course `undefined` which is all understandable. Let's add another property to constructor's prototype:

```
Counter.prototype.c = "third";
```

Right now, `counter.c` would return "third". But... we've changed our mind, lets get rid of those properties:

```
Counter.prototype = {};
```

Using simple logic, while overwriting `counter` prototype's `prototype` property, we would lose the properties for `counter` which we've added before to Counter.prototype. But that's not the case - `counter.c` Returns "third". I am lost here. So... let's try overwriting the value:

```
Counter.prototype.c = "fourth hohoho";
```

Nothing changes, counter.c still returns "third".

Why did it not succeed to remove the properties? What am I missing?

Comment: Look up how prototypes work in Javascript.

Comment: The constructor merely establishes the relationship between the new object and the constructor's `.prototype` object. After that point, the constructor is pretty much irrelevant. The relationship between the two objects is all that matters.

Comment: Duh, it turns out it's that trivial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you create your object, a *reference* to its prototype object is added to the prototype.

You can *augment* that prototype object, and because the instances share the reference, those changes will be reflected in any existing instances.

However if you *overwrite* the prototype object, the previously created instances still hold a reference to the original prototype object.

It's the same as what happens with this code:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;

a.foo = 'bar';    // augment 'a'
b.foo === 'bar';  // true

a = {};           // overwrite 'a'
b.foo === 'bar';  // still true
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add/remove properties from a prototype object dynamically, but you can't replace the prototype object of instances that have been already been created. In your example, instances created after you replaced the constructor's prototype property will get the new prototype, but the ones created before that will keep a reference to the former object.

If you want to clear some property from the prototype, remove them from the original object, using the `delete` operator:

```
delete Counter.prototype.c;
```

Comment: this just returns 'true' when trying in console. i am new to web dev , but i couldn't see any change in the existing or new objects created from a prototype before/after this statement is applied

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this? Try:

```js
function fa () {this.a=1}
var fb = new fa ();
fa.a = 2;
fa.prototype.a = 3;
var fc = new fa ();
console.log (fa.a, fb.a, fc.a);
```

From what you say it should print 2 1 3 but it prints 2 1 1

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The question was regarding why creating new prototype object haven't cleaned prototype in previously created object. And here the "1" is written instead of "3" because to get value of property "a", the object first checks it's existence and value in object, then in prototype chain.